# Copy Data activity in ADF creates strange temporary filenames

Tags: azure, csv, sftp, azure-data-factory

I am using a `Copy Data` activity to upload the contents of a database table as `.csv` files to an SFTP server using a self-hosted Integration Runtime.

The "owners" of the FTP site have pointed out that they are seeing "strange" filenames, i.e. a guid appended to the designated filename. When I look at the uploaded files, however, that suffix is gone.

It appears therefore that the `Copy Data` activity

```
(a) creates the file with a guid in the name,
(b) streams the content into the file, and
(c) renames the file at the end.
```

Can somebody confirm or deny this? Has anybody else seen this behaviour?

(The problem with this is obviously that step (a) triggers some processing in another system, which is a problem for me).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank, Martin

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you are describing indicates you have "Upload with temp file" checked (which I believe is the default) in your SFTP source:

[image]

You may uncheck this box if you don't want it or if the server doesn't support it.

Comment: No its different, he is asking about the strange GUID like folder creation. The option you shown is for temp file not for folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have raised this in Microsoft community to get answers as the error still persists in SFTP also when I tested in adf.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1329675/temporary-folders(ex-0c9f41ec-6866-425e-b7b3-ad18c